# SSRS: Bookmark/DocumentMap features are very slow in deployed report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When developing my report in BIDS, the Go to Bookmark action is pretty quick but after deploying my report to the server any bookmark click takes about 10 seconds with the "Loading" pop-up. My report is 1 (potentially long) page but it displays a lot of information so i wanted to be able to add a little index at the top. I've tried DocumentMapLabel as well but it's the same loading issue but I have no control over how gargantuan the side bar is for the tiny tree map it displays.

My query runs in less than a second so pretty much all of the time waiting is on SSRS.

Any ideas what is going on or if there are setting i can change to make it more snappy?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well, i work remotely so i'm not on the network that the report server is on directly. After remoting into a machine that is, the bookmark feature is nearly instantaneous. I'm not sure why it matters for this feature but I suppose i'll be testing my report on the remote machine instead.